# Ubuntu desktop ssh unreachable after a while

Tags: 20.04, openssh

Hi I installed a new Ubuntu Desktop machine wich i am running a server from. Now i ran into the issue that after a while (12-16 hours sometimes, after i didn't use it for a bit.) that when I try to connect to ssh again it sais it is unreachable and I do not know why.

I turned off sleep mode in the power options but that didn't help. Does anybody know what causes this? **Im trying to connect within my local network.**

Comment: Have you confirmed that the IP address of the machine has not changed?

Comment: yes its a static ip

Answer (score 0):

Verify that there isn't a firewall blocking the connection, that the SSH service is running on the instance, and that SSH tcp port 22 is in the listening state.
Try This.....

: Use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager

Note: Installation of the SSM Agent is required to use this method. For more information on Session Manager and a complete list of prerequisites, see Setting up Session Manager.

1. Open the AWS Systems Manager console.
2. Start a session.
3. To disable firewalls and restart the SSH service,run the following commands.

   ```
             # iptables -F
             # service sshd restart
   ```

Note: The preceding command flushes all main iptables rules, not just for port 22. After you regain access to your instance, review your firewall configuration (for example, ufw, firewalld, iptables).

4. Verify that the SSH tcp port (22) is in a listening state.

   ```
           # netstat -tnlp | grep :22**
   ```

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      849/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      849/sshd

5. Terminate the session.
6. Connect to the instance using SSH.
   Run the AWSSupport-TroubleshootSSH automation document

AWSSupport-TroubleshootSSH automation document installs the Amazon EC2Rescue tool on the instance. Then this tool checks for and corrects some issues that cause remote connection errors when connecting to a Linux machine through SSH. For more information, see How can I use the AWSSupport-TroubleshootSSH Automation workflow to troubleshoot SSH connection issues?

Comment: Thanks ill give it a shot

Comment: I have my firewall disabled and my ssh port is 12222.

Comment: I also cant boot up the pc its like itys stuck i get no screen when this happens.

Comment: It looks like your answer is part of some documentation. If that's the case, could you please add a reference to the documentation page?